# Java:If user type 'y'||'Y' quiz begins,'n'||'N' quiz end.For rest,it shows invalid. I want to show invalid when user type word starting with y or n

Tags: java, if-statement, char, java.util.scanner

I want the program to run only if it recieves 'y','Y','N' or 'n'. It doesn't work for other characters . However when user writes a more than 1 letter word with y or n (for e.g yddh,ndhdh, etc), the program still runs. please suggest what I can do. I tried taking 'a' as String but in if-else statement it showed error because string cannot be compared to char with == operator.

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
   class Main {
   static char a;


   public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("Do you want to play this quiz?");
   System.out.println("Type 'Y'for Yes or 'N' for no. It's case Insensitive.");
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
   a=sc.next().trim().charAt(0);

   if (a=='n'||a=='N')
   {System.out.println("Thanks for downloading!");
    System.exit(0);}

   else if ((a !='n'&&a !='N') && (a !='y'&& a !='Y'))
   {System.out.println("Invalid Syntax");
   System.exit(0);}


   else if(a=='y'||a=='Y')
   {System.out.println("Welcome to the quiz");}
    }
   }
```

Comment: Check for y/Y and n/N and just use an else for the rest, no need for a third check. (It will be confusing for the user if your program say only uppercase Y/N is allowed but then it allows also lowercase)

Answer (score 2):

Further to Subramanian Mariappan's and Yasham's answer, you can shorten the code by using `equalsIgnoreCase()` method as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Do you want to play this quiz?");
        System.out.println("Type 'Y'for Yes or 'N' for no. It's case Insensitive.");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = sc.next();

        if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            System.out.println("Thanks for downloading!");
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to the quiz");     
        } else  {
            System.out.println("Invalid Syntax");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```